# Detecting Java VM architecture on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows-10, java-web-start

I have following piece of code to detect if my app is running on 64-bit platform:

```
public static boolean is64BitVM() {
  String bits = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model", "?");
  logger.debug(String.format("sun.arch.data.model=%s", bits));
  if (bits.equals("64")) {
     return true;
  }
  String java_vm_name = System.getProperty("java.vm.name");
  logger.debug(String.format("java.vm.name=%s", java_vm_name));      

  String os_arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
  logger.debug(String.format("os.arch=%s", os_arch));

  if (bits.equals("?")) {
     // probably sun.arch.data.model isn't available
     // maybe not a Sun JVM?
     // try with the vm.name property
     return java_vm_name.toLowerCase().indexOf("64") >= 0;
    } 
  // probably 32bit
  return false;
}
```

It used to run nicely on Windows 7, but after upgrade to Windows 10 the same piece of code started to report 32bit architecture:

```
2015-11-05 17:53:15,429 DEBUG [javawsApplicationMain] sun.arch.data.model=32
2015-11-05 17:53:15,431 DEBUG [javawsApplicationMain] java.vm.name=Java   HotSpot(TM) Client VM
2015-11-05 17:53:15,431 DEBUG [javawsApplicationMain] os.arch=x86
```

What is strange is that it reports 32-bit architecture when run through JWS, but when I run it locally in my IDE I get proper result (64-bit).
Seems to be another freaking issue with Windows 10 security model.
Any thoughts?

Comment: are you sure you are running the Same VM? Do you have multiple installed?

Comment: do you have 32bit or 64bit JDK/JRE?

Comment: Which Version of jdk or jre ?

Comment: When run locally reported version is JDK 1.7.0_10 (this one detects 64-bit), when run through JWS, reported version is JDK 1.7.0_55 (this one detects 32-bits). This is pretty interesting as java -version from my command line gives yet another version (1.7.0_45) reported as 64-bit.

Comment: After a little bit of searching I found all three environments on my disk. And ineeded the one that was taken by JWS (1.7.0_55) is 32-bit one. I also found a setting in Java Configuration Panel deciding which Java to take - it was set to **c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe**. Tried to change it to **c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe** but that gave error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.deploy.config.WinPlatform.getPlatformUserHome()Ljava/lang/String;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked was to uninstall 32-bit version and then install latest 64-bit Java. At first I have installed Java 8 but I could not force my JWS app to be launched (even adding self-signed cert to exceptions as well as URL from .jnlp file did not help). Eventually installed latest Java 7 and that did the trick.